# Add a header to all responses in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to know how I can add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` to my headers.

I've tried this unsuccessfully:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
    return next.Invoke();
});
```

Answer (score 41):

Using `app.use(...)` and mutating `context.Response.Headers` from within `Startup.Configure` is correct, but it's important to do it at the right point in the chain. ASP.NET Core middleware components can "short-circuit" (see the [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index) docs), preventing further middleware from being called, and by experimenting with it I've inferred that `UseMvc()` does so. In an MVC application, then, this means you have to put your `app.use(...)` call *before* `app.UseMvc()`.

In other words, starting from the template ASP.NET Core 2.0 application that Visual Studio generates for you, you want to modify `Startup.Configure` in `Startup.cs` to look something like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    // Add header:
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
        return next.Invoke();
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: When app.UseMvc is last  the app.UseCors... works perfectly

Comment: Since it's the example here, it's worth noting that setting this particular header to `*` comes with security implication as it effectively disables the same-origin security policy, which can lead to cross-site request forgery attacks. Only use `*` when you want to open up ajax request access to the whole internet (e.g. in the context of a public API) and ensure that all non-idempotent requests you expose have some form of CSRF protection.

Answer (score 5):

I tried your code, and it worked beautifully... Placement is key: I'm pretty sure it needs to be early in the chain.

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        //app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
        app.Use((context, next) => {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
            return next.Invoke();
        });
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseSignalR();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use the in built **[CORS Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1)** in the asp.net core framework rather than creating your own Middleware.

In `Configure` method of the `Startup` class add the following code.

```
// Add CORS for YourAnotherSite
    app.UseCors(builder =>
       builder.WithOrigins("http://YourAnotherSite.com"));
```

**OR**

**Use Named Policies**

In `Configure` method of the `Startup` class

```
options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin",
        builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://YourAnotherSite.com"));
```

and then in the `ConfigureServices` method of the startup class.

`app.UseCors("AllowMyOrigin");`

Alternatively, the Policy can be applied at each **Controller** or **Action** methods.

Comment: Hi, using `app.UseCors` doesn't add a header to the response (or it doesn't seem to) but does it still achieve the same?

Comment: @Percy - The Cors Headers are only added for the Cross-domain requests. If you are requesting from the same Origin, the ASP.net core wouldn't add the CORS headers.

Answer (score 0):

We've found the ApplicationBuilder methods inconsistent too - it's not clear when the handler is handing back to the chain (for instance `UseStaticFiles()`) and when it's not (`UseMvc()`).

You don't say what environment you're running under, but if you're intending on using IIS then don't give up on `web.config` yet! The [url rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module works perfectly well, and allows you to set outbound rules on *all* request.

There's a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26545975/548664